# x86 cmp register and memory - where intermediate data is saved?

Tags: assembly, x86, emulation

Suppose I have such assembly instruction:

```
cmp sp 100h
```

I try to reproduce logical steps that x86 cpu does during execution. Like on this [schema](http://www.hartismere.com/Subjects/ICT/ALevelComputing/CPUCycleAnimation). Where does cpu store immediate value `100h`? On this link used something named *accumulator* (AC). Is there are general purpose register (EAX?) or extra register to hold this data before comparison execution within ALU?

Comment: It's not stored in the accumulator.  IIRC, the CPU has a temporary register it is stored in, while the comparison takes place.

Comment: Is temporary register not one of general EAX, EBX, etc?

Comment: Immediate values are typically encoded right into the instruction.

Comment: @jeff-mercado Ok, but I have 16 bit words and `cmp sp 100h` encoded into 4 bytes. CPU fetch only 2 bytes per each memory access. Thus my cpu emulator should store intermediate data somewhere... And I want do this like on real hardware.

Comment: The way to look at it is to see that there is a wire coming from the instruction register or decoder straight to the ALU.

Comment: [Here's an example](http://www.eng.utah.edu/~cs3810/Homework/homework07/cpu.jpg) diagram for reference of what appears to be a simplified RISC CPU. x86 has similar properties but is much more complex. The `Instruction[15-0]` line (bottom-left of image) can be an input to the ALU.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is somewhat confusing, but I will attempt to answer.

When encoding an assembly instruction, immediate data is typically encoded in the instruction itself. For example

```
cmp     esp,100h
81 fc00010000
```

If we check the cmp encoding, we see that 81 is the first byte to an opcode containing a reference to a 32bit register, and a 4 byte immediate.

Skipping forward to your comparison to fetch/decode/execute/store and your comment on CPU fetching, well, modern CPUs are quite a bit more complicated.

Suffice to say (in this scope) that x86 instruction fetching is complicated, because x86 opcodes are variable length. Meaning that the CPU knows that it needs to fetch N bytes, in this case 6 bytes (1 for opcode, 1 for first operand, 4 for immediate value).

Now "holding" the immediate value is quite implementation specific, but in this case I expect it will be encoded into the actual "instruction" the CPU executes. In some cases, the data is saved into a temporary register.

---

A good book on all this stuff, and far more is [Inside the Machine by Jon Stokes](http://www.nostarch.com/insidemachine.htm)